# php chmod change an uploaded file permissions [chmod not working ]

Tags: php

I am coding a site that users can upload images to view in a carousel and i made it to uploading a file
but i can't open it so first i thought the file was corrupt but when i open the properties i found out that the file was not corrupt by his Size so i used :-

```
chmod($path, octdec(0755));
```

***but the file still not opening***

**the hole code :-**

```
<?
$account = 'account';
$price = '10.5';
require_once 'Config.php';

$dbCon = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name";
$conn = new PDO($dbCon, $username, $password);
$msg ='';
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo $name;
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $path = 'upload/' .$image;
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO special (imageurl) VALUES ('$path')");
    $query->execute(); 
    if($query){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$path);
            chmod($path, octdec(0755));
echo $path;
        $msg = "Done";
    }else{
        $msg = "Error Some thing went Wrong!";
    }
}
?>
```

BTW : i'm using Appserv 8.6.0 running on PHP 5.6.30

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly is not working? Do you get an error?  Does the file get uploaded to the temporary location?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld the file is uploaded to server but the problem when i open the file says **you don't have the correct permissions to access the file location**

Comment: Ok does it work when you change the permissions manually for the file? (to 0755)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld First Thanks for your quick response , And Yes it work when i change the [ picture ] permissions manually

Comment: You're using octdec(). I see that in user-contributed notes of chmod php-manual but I can't understand why to be honest because chmod needs an octal value and octdec converts an octal to decimal value.  Try just chmod($path, 0755) (without quotes around 0755!). You could also try $res = chmod($path, 0755) and if it works it should return true.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld i tried                                                                         
                `<?
  $changemod = chmod('C:\AppServ\www\Lab\upload\18.jpg', 0755);
  if ($changemod){
   echo 'permissions has been changed sucssefuly';
  }else{
   
   echo 'Error!';
  }                                                                                                                    
                ?>`                                                                                                        returns true **[ permissions has been changed ]**

Comment: Did it work to view the image after your actual permission change programmatically?